# Heroku & delayed_job - is there a way to autoscale named queues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

I'm using [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) together with [workless](https://github.com/lostboy/workless) which autoscales workers to 1 on Heroku.

delayed_job now allows you to easily create multiple named queues, however I can't find a way to scale these different queues.

For example I have 1 queue called "stats" where I don't mind having just 1 worker processing the whole thing even if it takes longer, whereas for other queues I would want to scale more than just 1 worker to finish them as quickly as possible - while making sure these workers only work on their own queues.

I think [HireFireApp](http://hirefireapp.com/) is working on something like this but it's not ready yet.

Are there any solutions out there for this?